# watchface service not showing on square devices

Tags: android, service, metadata, wear-os

I'm developing a Watchface (for AndroidWear), which works perfectly on round emulators and real devices, but I can't select the Watchface-Service on a square emulator.

Following a snippet of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
    <service
        android:name=".WatchFaceService"
        android:label="@string/app_label"
        android:allowEmbedded="true"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/watch_face" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview"
            android:resource="@drawable/preview_square" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.preview_circular"
            android:resource="@drawable/preview_circular"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.companionConfigurationAction"
            android:value="com.example.android.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_ANALOG" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.category.WATCH_FACE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

I searched for misspellings, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, is that your watch face doesn't show on a square emulator only?

Comment: exactly. Because of that i suppose that the mistake is in the manifest.

Comment: Is your emulator a Lollipop one?

Comment: no, kitkat wear. -but i'll test it with a Lollipop Emulator

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as i figured out: I have to use at least Lollipop.